# Errors when running my Turbo-C HelloWorld example 

Tags: c

When I run simple printf command, I get the following errors:

```
First.c 1: Unable to open file stdio.h
First.c 2: Unable to create output file 'D:\TCC\First.obj'
```

Please let me know what I did wrong here.

Platform : Windows
IDE: Turbo C

Comment: What is the full code and how are you compiling?

Comment: And what platform are you on?

Comment: and what is the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: Please look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-turbo-c

Answer (score 2):

**Solution in Windows**

check [this link](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070420045034AAtLR8Z) and below solution:

*this solution copied form one of stackoverflow.com pages*

Check if you have anything like those stdio.h file and other header files under INCLUDE folder and LIB folder. LIB contains some files. In my case, I had the same issue but both of these folder were blank.. good to know. Steps:

1. Press: ALT + O + D (i.e. press ATL (keep pressed) and then O english character) and then D).
2. You'll see a popup window.
3. This window will have values for INCLUDE and LIB directories. The by default value for these two boxes in the popup window are: Drive leter where you installed TC... i.e. C:\ or D:\ or whatever followed by the path for INCLUDE and LIB folder. So, in my case,

INCLUDE box was set to: "C:\TC\INCLUDE" and LIB directory value box was set to: "C:\TC\LIB" (without quotes). Steps to resolve:

1. Press ALT + C.
2. Set your current directory as C:\TC\BGI
3. Press ALT + O + D, and put ../INCLUDE and ../LIB in Include/Lib directory values.
4. and now... when you'll run your progress, you'll say thanks to me. I like the archduchess C fractal graphics that I'm running on DOS Turbo C right now. Lol.

---

**Solution in Linux**

(not in case of this question but commonly this method is one of useful methods)

may be you are in linux and you have some missing .h and other library files. do this if you are in linux (this command works only on debian based distributions of linux ):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

for the others like fedora you can use this equivalent:

```
# yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel byacc
```

or try

```
# yum groupinstall ‘Development Tools’

# yum groupinstall ‘Development Libraries’
```

Comment: I have turbo c program where I made sample program just to print hello

Comment: I am compiling by pressing Alt+F9

Comment: `#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
printf("hello");
}`

It gave 2 errors:

1. First.c 1: Unable to open file stdio.h
2. First.c 2: Unable to create output file 'D:\TCC\First.obj'

Comment: @Maziar: He specifically said he is on windows. It would have been better if you suggested him to get a modern compiler/IDE..

Comment: @Thrustmaster: yeeeees Dear Thrustmaster! i save this solution for last level of the game. you advise me to edit my answer and replace it with a suggestion or suggest this in a comment?

Comment: Comments are just for discussion. Not many go through them. If there's anything important that future readers must know of, it always best to put it in the answer. So please update it with links to modern compilers. :)

Comment: I have set the includes and lib directories and now its pretty fine with errors. But program is not executing when I do CTRL + F9. However there are 0 errors when I  press ALT + F9

Comment: I am running on Windows 7. Is that problem?

Comment: if you are not bound up to use turbo c, use a modern IDE. it will be compatible with any new OS and full of cool features. if you are OK with new IDE say me to introduce it to you

Answer (score 0):

**Solution under Windows**
*Turbo has strange shorthand rules for file and directory names.*
For example:
     The location of my Turbo:
          C:\TC200
          C:\TC200\INCLUDE
          C:\TC200\LIB
          C:\TC200\MYPROJECTS

My Turbo's Options->Directories settings:
          Include directories: C:\TC200\INCLUDE
          Library directories: C:\TC200\LIB
          Output directory: **C:\TC200\MYPROJECTS**
          Turbo C directory: C:\TC200

*Note that the above highlight setting is wrong, the right way is* **C:\TC200\MYPROJ~1**